# Pass list items as arguments to method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming i have a method definition like this `do_stuff(*arg)`.

I have a list of values, `['a','b',...]`. How best can i pass the values of this list as individual arguments to the `do_stuff` method as `do_stuff('a','b',...)` ?

I've unsuccessfully tried using list comprehension - `do_stuff([str(value) for value in some_list])`

I am hoping i don't have to change `do_stuff()` to accept a list

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `*`,... A list comprehension just creates a list, you *already have a list*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them using the "*" operator. So an example would be like this:

```
def multiplyfouritems(a,b,c,d):
    return a*b*c*d

multiplyfouritems(*[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not an operator. It's part of the function-call syntax.

Comment: And it's called "splat" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same syntax, with the `*`:

```
do_stuff(*['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Thank you!. Knew it was something obvious